# numpy append changes int to float and adds zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I need to transform ranges to consecutive numbers. The ranges are in ints and the result should be the same. This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

mydata = np.array (
[49123400, 49123499],
[33554333, 33554337])

numbers_list = np.empty((0))
base_dir = "/foo.csv"

for x in mydata:
    numbers = np.arange(x[0], x[1]+1)
    numbers_list = np.append(numbers_list, numbers, axis=0)
np.savetxt(base_dir, numbers_list, delimiter=";")
```

What I would like to see is a list like that:

```
49123400,
49123401,
49123402,...
49123499,
33554333,
33554334,...
33554399
```

But what I get is:

```
4.912340000000000000e+11 and so on...
```

Where am I going wrong? Why is there a change from int to float, when I am doing the append?

Comment: What are your data types for `mydata`, `numbers_list`, and `numbers`?

Comment: mydata: int64, numbers: int64, numbers_list turns into float64

Comment: Note: base_dir vs basedir. Output is correct when I run your code, in range of 4.91E+07.

Comment: I see you edited the typo; are you sure the typo wasn't the cause of the confusion? Were you looking at the right file?

Comment: Yes, I am sure this was not the issue. In the original, it was ok. I had to type the code directly, as I could not copy / paste it and made a typo. Sorry.

Comment: 2 issues - the `np.empty` and the `fmt` in `savetxt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One important lesson to learn is that you should always choose the right data structure for your problem. In most cases if you want to append/concatenate then [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) is the wrong choice, except you can trivially setup the final array (with its final shape) and alter it by setting slices of it.

In this case the obvious choice would be to use a normal [python](/questions/tagged/python) `list` and `range`:

```
mydata = [[49123400, 49123499],
          [33554333, 33554337]]

mynewdata = []
for sublist in mydata:
    mynewdata.extend(range(sublist[0], sublist[1]+1))

>>> mynewdata
  [49123400, 49123401, 49123402, 49123403, 49123404, 49123405,
   49123406, 49123407, 49123408, 49123409, 49123410, 49123411,
   49123412, 49123413, 49123414, 49123415, 49123416, 49123417,
   49123418, 49123419, 49123420, 49123421, 49123422, 49123423,
   49123424, 49123425, 49123426, 49123427, 49123428, 49123429,
   49123430, 49123431, 49123432, 49123433, 49123434, 49123435,
   49123436, 49123437, 49123438, 49123439, 49123440, 49123441,
   49123442, 49123443, 49123444, 49123445, 49123446, 49123447,
   49123448, 49123449, 49123450, 49123451, 49123452, 49123453,
   49123454, 49123455, 49123456, 49123457, 49123458, 49123459,
   49123460, 49123461, 49123462, 49123463, 49123464, 49123465,
   49123466, 49123467, 49123468, 49123469, 49123470, 49123471,
   49123472, 49123473, 49123474, 49123475, 49123476, 49123477,
   49123478, 49123479, 49123480, 49123481, 49123482, 49123483,
   49123484, 49123485, 49123486, 49123487, 49123488, 49123489,
   49123490, 49123491, 49123492, 49123493, 49123494, 49123495,
   49123496, 49123497, 49123498, 49123499, 33554333, 33554334,
   33554335, 33554336, 33554337]
```

This can be trivially converted to a `numpy.array`:

```
>>> np.array(mynewdata)
array([49123400, 49123401, 49123402, 49123403, 49123404, 49123405,
       49123406, 49123407, 49123408, 49123409, 49123410, 49123411,
       49123412, 49123413, 49123414, 49123415, 49123416, 49123417,
       49123418, 49123419, 49123420, 49123421, 49123422, 49123423,
       49123424, 49123425, 49123426, 49123427, 49123428, 49123429,
       49123430, 49123431, 49123432, 49123433, 49123434, 49123435,
       49123436, 49123437, 49123438, 49123439, 49123440, 49123441,
       49123442, 49123443, 49123444, 49123445, 49123446, 49123447,
       49123448, 49123449, 49123450, 49123451, 49123452, 49123453,
       49123454, 49123455, 49123456, 49123457, 49123458, 49123459,
       49123460, 49123461, 49123462, 49123463, 49123464, 49123465,
       49123466, 49123467, 49123468, 49123469, 49123470, 49123471,
       49123472, 49123473, 49123474, 49123475, 49123476, 49123477,
       49123478, 49123479, 49123480, 49123481, 49123482, 49123483,
       49123484, 49123485, 49123486, 49123487, 49123488, 49123489,
       49123490, 49123491, 49123492, 49123493, 49123494, 49123495,
       49123496, 49123497, 49123498, 49123499, 33554333, 33554334,
       33554335, 33554336, 33554337])
```

or even simply written to a file without bothering about arrays:

```
with open('yourfile', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(mynewdata).replace(',', ';'))
```

And finally a note on why you converted your integers to `floats`:

```
>>> np.empty((0))
array([], dtype=float64)
```

The `np.empty` creates a float array and so append/concatenate will always result in `float` arrays. Use `np.empty(0, int)` if you wanted an integer array:

```
>>> np.empty(0, int)
array([], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Hi, this was really helpful. Not only did you provide the solution, but you also explained, what was going wrong.
I found one further error in my initial posting: mydata[[xxxxx]] must actually be mydata([xxx]). And as I have to forward the result in Excel, it helped to change the replace part to replace(',', ';\n'), so I have them nicely listed. Tx. a lot for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

It helps in cases like this to step through it in an iteractive session, and look at `shape` and `dtype` at each step.

```
In [254]: mydata = np.array( [
     ...: [49123400, 49123499],
     ...: [33554333, 33554337]])
In [255]: mydata
Out[255]: 
array([[49123400, 49123499],
       [33554333, 33554337]])
In [256]: mydata.shape
Out[256]: (2, 2)
In [257]: mydata.dtype
Out[257]: dtype('int32')
In [258]: numbers_list = np.empty((0))
In [259]: numbers_list
Out[259]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

Note that `numbers_list` is a float array.  Look into providing `empty` with a `dtype`

```
In [260]: x=mydata[0]
In [261]: numbers = np.arange(x[0],x[1]+1)
In [262]: numbers.dtype
Out[262]: dtype('int32')
In [263]: numbers.shape
Out[263]: (100,)
In [264]: numbers_list = np.append(numbers_list, numbers, axis=0)
In [265]: numbers_list.shape
Out[265]: (100,)
In [266]: numbers_list.dtype
Out[266]: dtype('float64')
```

After concatenating these 2 arrays, the result has the dtype of the `numbers_list`.

So changing that `empty` dtype should preserve the `int` dtype.

I have been on a crusade against `np.append`.  This is another example of its misuse.  It is just a form of `np.concatenate`, and often is a poor substitute for a list append

I'd suggest building a list and using one concatenate

```
In [267]: numbers_list = [np.arange(x[0],x[1]+1) for x in mydata]
In [268]: len(numbers_list)
Out[268]: 2
In [269]: np.concatenate(numbers_list)
Out[269]: 
array([49123400, 49123401, 49123402, 49123403, 49123404, 49123405,
       49123406, 49123407, 49123408, 49123409, 49123410, 49123411,
       49123412, 49123413, 49123414, 49123415, 49123416, 49123417,
       49123418, 49123419, 49123420, 49123421, 49123422, 49123423,
       49123424, 49123425, 49123426, 49123427, 49123428, 49123429,
  ...
       49123496, 49123497, 49123498, 49123499, 33554333, 33554334,
       33554335, 33554336, 33554337])
In [270]: _.shape
Out[270]: (105,)
```

Since you are using `savetxt` to write the numbers, look at it's `fmt` parameter.  The default is that scienctific notation.

With the correct `fmt` you will get integers:

```
In [272]: arr=np.concatenate(numbers_list)
In [273]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr,fmt='%d',delimiter=',')
In [274]: cat test.txt
49123400
49123401
49123402
49123403
49123404
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with appending columns to numpy array. i was using `np.arange()` function to make a sample array with one column, then i was appending columns to it but the data was getting messy as you can see :

```
[[  0.00000000e+00  -1.56000000e+00]
[  1.00000000e+00   2.43000000e+00]
[  2.00000000e+00  -9.40000000e-01]
..., 
[  4.99700000e+03  -1.99000000e+00]
[  4.99800000e+03   4.10000000e-01]
[  4.99900000e+03  -7.00000000e-02]]
```

the problem didn't go anyway even by ensuring the equality of dtypes but finally got solved by using `np.zeros()` instead of `np.arange()`.