# int insert into np.array float array becomes a float with bunch of 0s with e^02

Tags: python

I have the following (1, 64) np.array:

```
tmp = [2.0526170e-03 1.2926349e-03 1.6969059e-03 3.3049309e-04 6.6263149e-03
 2.9519806e-03 2.0714400e-03 5.4122265e-03 2.7082241e-03 3.1686751e-03
 1.3918726e-04 3.8752297e-04 3.2962889e-03 3.2280399e-03 7.2885421e-03
 3.1624420e-04 6.6712254e-04 4.0910598e-03 5.7867495e-04 1.2561013e-03
 1.1196338e-03 1.4153749e-03 2.6155743e-03 8.1474101e-03 1.8185090e-03
 8.7743643e-04 3.7411891e-03 1.7805353e-03 5.3422892e-04 7.8337354e-04
 5.9816906e-05 4.0453982e-05 8.3250977e-04 5.3460896e-04 5.6111699e-10
 1.3029578e-03 6.8478996e-04 3.4205094e-03 2.3914864e-03 5.3406606e-04
 6.6411062e-03 1.0759196e-03 1.1909866e-03 4.7715430e-04 3.2101159e-03
 1.3727898e-02 1.3080131e-03 3.8353755e-04 2.5187498e-03 2.2409221e-03
 7.2773243e-04 4.3422016e-03 5.0830361e-03 1.2181720e-03 1.7945823e-04
 4.1899364e-03 7.7990706e-05 3.8116740e-04 2.1038472e-03 2.1316914e-03
 9.9269630e-05 1.3454767e-03 1.1122935e-02 1.5853636e-03]
```

and I am trying to add an int value to the first and last position using

```
tmp = tmp.flatten() 
tmp = np.concatenate([[785], tmp, [785 + 1]])
```

but for some reason I am getting:

```
[7.85000000e+02 2.05261703e-03 1.29263487e-03 1.69690594e-03
 3.30493087e-04 6.62631495e-03 2.95198057e-03 2.07143999e-03
 5.41222654e-03 2.70822411e-03 3.16867512e-03 1.39187265e-04
 3.87522974e-04 3.29628889e-03 3.22803995e-03 7.28854211e-03
 3.16244201e-04 6.67122542e-04 4.09105979e-03 5.78674953e-04
 1.25610130e-03 1.11963379e-03 1.41537492e-03 2.61557428e-03
 8.14741012e-03 1.81850896e-03 8.77436425e-04 3.74118914e-03
 1.78053533e-03 5.34228922e-04 7.83373544e-04 5.98169063e-05
 4.04539824e-05 8.32509773e-04 5.34608960e-04 5.61116986e-10
 1.30295777e-03 6.84789964e-04 3.42050940e-03 2.39148643e-03
 5.34066057e-04 6.64110621e-03 1.07591960e-03 1.19098660e-03
 4.77154303e-04 3.21011594e-03 1.37278978e-02 1.30801310e-03
 3.83537554e-04 2.51874980e-03 2.24092207e-03 7.27732433e-04
 4.34220163e-03 5.08303614e-03 1.21817202e-03 1.79458235e-04
 4.18993644e-03 7.79907059e-05 3.81167396e-04 2.10384722e-03
 2.13169144e-03 9.92696296e-05 1.34547672e-03 1.11229355e-02
 1.58536364e-03 7.86000000e+02]
```

where the array I am expecting is:

```
[785. 2.05261703e-03 1.29263487e-03 1.69690594e-03
 3.30493087e-04 6.62631495e-03 2.95198057e-03 2.07143999e-03
 5.41222654e-03 2.70822411e-03 3.16867512e-03 1.39187265e-04
 3.87522974e-04 3.29628889e-03 3.22803995e-03 7.28854211e-03
 3.16244201e-04 6.67122542e-04 4.09105979e-03 5.78674953e-04
 1.25610130e-03 1.11963379e-03 1.41537492e-03 2.61557428e-03
 8.14741012e-03 1.81850896e-03 8.77436425e-04 3.74118914e-03
 1.78053533e-03 5.34228922e-04 7.83373544e-04 5.98169063e-05
 4.04539824e-05 8.32509773e-04 5.34608960e-04 5.61116986e-10
 1.30295777e-03 6.84789964e-04 3.42050940e-03 2.39148643e-03
 5.34066057e-04 6.64110621e-03 1.07591960e-03 1.19098660e-03
 4.77154303e-04 3.21011594e-03 1.37278978e-02 1.30801310e-03
 3.83537554e-04 2.51874980e-03 2.24092207e-03 7.27732433e-04
 4.34220163e-03 5.08303614e-03 1.21817202e-03 1.79458235e-04
 4.18993644e-03 7.79907059e-05 3.81167396e-04 2.10384722e-03
 2.13169144e-03 9.92696296e-05 1.34547672e-03 1.11229355e-02
 1.58536364e-03 786.]
```

any ideas why this is happening ?
tks in advance

PS.: this error is similar to [numpy append changes int to float and adds zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146831/numpy-append-changes-int-to-float-and-adds-zeros/65966993#65966993) but the solution proposed did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you need to set the dtype of the array as "object":

```
import numpy as np

tmp = [2.0526170e-03, 1.2926349e-03, 1.6969059e-03]
#set the dtype to object
tmp = np.array(tmp,dtype = 'object')
tmp = tmp.flatten() 
tmp = np.concatenate([[785], tmp, [785 + 1]])
```

You may find some explanation here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html